# Нужно ли ставить тире в пословице?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, пословицы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли будет поставить тире после слова «человека» в этой пословице?
*Птицу узнают в полёте, а человека (?) в работе.*

Comment: В шапке вопроса недобор буквы, в тексте — знаков препинания. Правильно будет проверить?

Comment: Обычно в пословицах не ставят тире. Тире это новомодный знак. В пословицах обходятся интонационной запятой разделяющих два фразеологизма. Внутри фразеологизма нет никаких дополнительных интонаций в этом суть.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно. В большинстве случаев в этих пословицах **ставится тире**.

**Птицу узнают в полете, а человека — в работе.** [пропущено "узнают"]
Знай птицу по перьям, а молодца — по ухватке.
Красна птица пером, а человек — умом да делами.
Красна птица перьями, а человек — знанием.
Птицу узнают по полету, а человека — по работе.

В ПАС под ред. Лопатина ([Тире в неполном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=107#pp107)):

> § 16. В неполных предложениях на месте пропущенных членов предложения или их частей **ставится тире**.
> **1.** В частях сложного предложения с параллельной структурой, а также в простом предложении с однородными повторяющимися членами предложения, где пропущенный член восстанавливается из первой части предложения: <...> *У него одна история неизбежно вызывает в памяти другую, а та — третью, третья — четвертую, и потому нет его рассказам конца* (Пауст.)...

Пословица — это краткое народное изречение с назидательным смыслом. Обычно в самом конце предложения и требуется эта назидательная пауза, которую удобно на письме показать с помощью тире.

Answer (score 2):

1. Тире можно поставить **по интонации**:

***ПтИцу** узнают **в полЁте**, а **человЕка** — **в рабОте.***

Такая интонация называется **параллельной.**

Это сложное предложение, союз ***А*** — сопоставительный. Грамматическая конституция позволяет  **сравнить две ситуации.**

**[Розенталь, пункт 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93)**

Тире ставится в неполных предложениях **при параллелизме конструкций** (предложений или частей предложения): Её [литературы] красота — в истине, её главное значение — в правде (Кор.); О, я хочу безумно жить, всё сущее — увековечить, безличное — вочеловечить, несбывшееся — воплотить! (Бл.);

2. Но это же предложение можно прочитать **без параллельной интонации**, и тогда паузы и тире не нужно:

*Птицу узнают **в полЁте,** а человека **в рабОте.***

Comment: Вот! Хорошо, что добавили безпаузность, а то я уже хотел опять маненько критикнуть.

Comment: В двух темах сразу отвечаю..

Comment: Спасибо большое, я очень рада, что нашла ваш сайт. Но я так и не поняла, будет ли ошибкой, если не поставить тире. Ведь тире заменяет сказуемое..

Comment: И мы рады всем, кто любит русский язык)  Нет, не будет ошибкой. У Розенталя в п. 5 написано При отсутствии ПАУЗЫ в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится: Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку (Ч.); Из нашей батареи только Солёный пойдёт на барже, мы же со строевой частью (Ч.); Алёша смотрел на них, а они на него (Дост.); У вора один грех., а у нас с хозяином десять (Остр.); …Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93

Comment: @Мария  Приветствую вас на сайте. К сведению: здесь принято благодарить участников, отмечая все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.